# Why am I getting an invalid pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, free, glibc

I'm writing a backtracking problem for homework, and all the code works except for my `delete[]` at the end.

```
/*Assg4.cc*/
int main()
{
    //removed irrelevant code - see pastebin links if needed

    void *data = &datavector;
    bool finished = false;
    bool* continuance = &finished;
    int *a = new int[n+1];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = NULL;
    }

    delete []a;
    delete continuance;

return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> *** glibc detected *** ./Assg4: free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfc7098f ***

The function `backtrack()` merely fills the contents of the array `a[]` at some point, it doesn't delete, expand, or shrink the array in any way. I know the problem is with the deletes at the end, because when I comment them out I get no error (and the result of all computations is correct). What am I doing wrong?

Pastebin full files:

[Assg4.cc](http://pastebin.com/aZQpNgGk)

[backtrack.cc & backtrack.h](http://pastebin.com/46AsrHEP)

Comment: I don't have the rep to post more than 2 links, that's why backtrack.cc & backtrack.h are in the same paste

Comment: delete what you new, delete[] what you new[].  You didn't new `finished`.

Comment: Your use of pointers seems arbitrary.

Comment: @andre - I have to implement the defined functions of backtrack.h. The use of pointers there is confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure your error is actually here:

```
delete continuance;
```

You're trying to delete something allocated on the stack, since `continuance` points to `finished`, which is allocated on the stack (without a call to `new`). Items on the stack will be destroyed automatically when they go out of scope, so you don't have to worry about deleting `continuance`.

See: [What and where are the stack and heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: You're right - I thought I had tested it with just `delete []a`, but I didn't. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
bool finished = false;
bool* continuance = &finished;

delete continuance;
```

You are calling `delete` on a pointer which is not allocated using `new`. This is causing an **Undefined Behavior**.
`finished` is a automatic/local variable which is autmatically destroyed once the scope `{ }` in which it is declared ends.

The rule is simple:

***Don't call `delete` unless you called `new`.***